# How to extract data correctly when using linq in sql asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an Excel data that contains records from different tables, the problem is if there is no record on any year, my Excel must do the same. Same, if there is data, but currently data on my Excel does not do this and need some help on my logic below. The Excel is duplicating data throughout to any year and week, yet on the front end I check it does not do this at all and need some help on my back end.

```cs
public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
{
    var db = new ProductionManagementEntities();

    var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                    
                        from m in db.Models
                        from mx in db.Models
                        from mt in db.Models
                        from mv in db.Models
                        from wk in db.Models

                        join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
                        orderby w.Year descending , m.Name descending, p.ProductionDate descending, w.WeekNum descending, mt.Name descending, mx.Name descending, mv.Name descending
               
                        where (mx.InActive == true)
                        where (mt.InActive == false)
                        where(m.InActive == false)
                        where(mv.InActive == false)
                        
                        where (mt.Name == "VW270")
                        where(mx.Name == "VW250")
                        where(m.Name == "VW270PA")
                        where(mv.Name == "VW250/2PA")

                        select new ExtractionViewModel
                        {
                            Year = w.Year,
                            Day = p.ProductionDate,
                            Week = w.WeekNum,
                            VW270 = mt.Name,
                            VW270PA = m.Name,
                            VW250 = mx.Name,
                            VW2502PA = mv.Name
                        }).ToList();

    return scheduleList;
}
    
// Model
public class ExtractionViewModel
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }

    public string VW250 { get; set; }
    public string VW270 { get; set; }
    public string VW2502PA { get; set; }
    public string VW270PA { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DataResult()
{
    return View(this.GetExtractionViewModels());
}

public void ExportToExcel()
{
    var v = new GridView();
    v.DataSource = this.GetExtractionViewModels();
    v.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExtractionRecords.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
    v.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    //return View("DataResult");
}
```

Excel output:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

SQL query on Week table:

````sql
SELECT TOP (1000) [WeekId]
      ,[WeekNum]
      ,[Year]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[InActive]
FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Week]
where WeekNum = 53
order by Year
```[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsbRq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMVLH.png
````

Comment: What does the query that the front-end uses look like? Or is `GetExtractionViewModels()` the method that your front-end uses?

Comment: @stemado, i have attached it on the topic have a look.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the `ExtractionViewModel` class? If so, can you add a an Id Property `public int Id {get;set;}` and have it set with `p.Id` in `new ExtractionViewModel { Id = p.Id, Year = w.Year, etc...}`.

That way you can see which records in the join are being duplicated.

Comment: @Stemado yes the records are now duplicating and trying to avoid that, not sending correct values as output. Mind sharing this logic below my topic?